# Use a CQWP to create a list of document libraries

Tags: 2010, document-library, rest, content-query-web-part, data-view-web-part

I have a site with a large number of document libraries. There are constant adds / archiving of document libraries, so the list changes.

Is it possible to generate a dynamic list of links to these libraries using a CQWP / DVWP?

Comment: You mean to list all document libraries in a particular site or sitecollection?

Comment: @AmalHashim - yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you can query SharePoint Web service and use GetListCollection method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getlistcollection(v=office.14).aspx

You can ease the programming by using [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/).

```
$().SPServices({     
    operation: "GetListCollection",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=List]").each(function() {
        var list_Title = $(this).attr("Title");
        var list_URL = $(this).attr("DefaultViewUrl");
        //Add logic to display hyperlinks
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: that's c#\vb.  trying to minimalize hard coding for reuse